# how can i write multiple paragraphs and multiple images so that both can scroll together? Now i have this programing

Tags: java, android, xml

how can I write multiple paragraphs and multiple images so that both can scroll together? This is my programming. now tell me what I have to add to get scrolling text and images???

```
public class Page1Activity extends Activity {

    private ScrollView vscroll2;
    private ImageView imageview3;
    private TextView textview6;




    private Intent i = new Intent();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.page1);
        initialize();
        initializeLogic();
    }

    private void  initialize() {
        vscroll2 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.vscroll2);
        imageview3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview3);
        textview6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview6);


        imageview3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View _v) { 

            }
        });

    }

    private void  initializeLogic() {
        setTitle("page 1");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
                i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ScrollView, you can only have one child class.

So you can use like this.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text_view" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text_view" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text_view" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text_view" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text_view" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text_view" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text_view" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text_view" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text_view" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you very much... its working fine according to my need.

Comment: I'm glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to abb multiple paragraphs and images in same pattern  in a sigle screen multiple times use
 ListView (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)
or RecyclerView
(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)
And if it is just a normal page with paragraphs and images with no fix repetative pattern; you have to add the imageviews and textviews as many time as they appear on screen to a layout first as its children and then add this layout to a scroll view. You can see the bellow example 
http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-scrollview-example